# segfault when closing a file on the destruction of the main window

Tags: c, gtk

I'm writing a GTK application that does some operations on a file, I have the following code:

```
gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
FILE *config_file;
config_file=fopen("home/user/config","r");
 gtk_signal_connect (GTK_OBJECT (main_window), "destroy",GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC (destroy), &config_file);
```

and the destroy funtion:

```
void destroy(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer config_file) {
  fclose((FILE *)config_file);
  gtk_main_quit ();
}
```

running the program in gdb yields the following backtrace:

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x0000003696072831 in _IO_new_file_close_it () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00000036960664f8 in fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

I have omitted the rest of the output because it was gtk related

Comment: so basically: why doesn't `FILE *config_file = ...; fclose((FILE*)&config_file);` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to give gtk_signal_connect "config_file" instead of "&config_file", since it is already a pointer.

In your comment, you write fclose ((FILE*)&config_file); This is wrong, too, leave it as in your original code stated in your question

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking if `fopen` failed. Maybe that will reveal some more information? If it did fail, then you'd be passing a null pointer to `gtk_signal_connect`.